# DateTime Parsing from DropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

im dealing with parsing a date comming from a dropdownlist that is filled before from Sql.
When the date is for ex. 11/15/2013 12:00:00 AM there is no problem, but when the date is 11/5/2013 12:00:00 AM it crashes (its not getting de 0)...is there any solution for these or i just have to do switch or if's?

Here is the parsing

```
 var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(day.SelectedValue, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        String dayText = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Thx all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for the parsing:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(day.SelectedValue, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The single `M`, `d` and `h` will accept the non-leading-zeros-format, assuming that's what you meant with:

> (its not getting de 0)

Funny though; because you probably are filling your dropdown-list with a parsed `DateTime` object, you should have full control of the back and forward parsing.